# Angular - cannot iterate over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to iterate over array but not able to do so (its an array under array).
It gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
```

I am not using toUpperCase anywhere.

The typescript code is :

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.data = [
          {
              'name': 'Task 1',
              'to_do': ['ToDo1', 'ToDo2', 'ToDo3']
          },
          {
              'name': 'Task 2',
              'to_do': ['ToDo4', 'ToDo5', 'ToDo6']
          }
      ];

  }
```

The template code is:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        Create New Task: <input type="text" name="task" />

        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let task of data; let i=index; let todo=task.to_do;">
            <div>
              {{ task.name }}
              {{ todo }}
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let do of todo">
              <input type="text" name="to_do" value="{{ do }}" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: where are you calling in your code above (toUpperCase), is the code above complete?

Comment: This kind of error usually occurs when you call (toUpperCase) to a (null) value

Comment: I am not using toUpperCase in component or template anywhere

Comment: Could you provide more of that error stack, we can then see what's really happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a template parsing error caused by `let todo=task.to_do;`

You can only declare local variables for `ngFor`'s exported values (index, odd, even, ...)

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Try this

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let task of data; let i=index; ">
        <div>
          {{ task.name }}
          {{ task.to_do}}
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let do of task.to_do">
          <input type="text" name="to_do" value="{{ do }}" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Note**: There is an `$implicit` value exported by `ngFor`, which equals to the current item in the loop.  However, the following does not work (I think it can only evaluate simple assignments

```
 <li *ngFor="let task of data; let i=index; let todo=$implicit.to_do;">
```

However,it will work using the `ng-template` form of `ngFor`, with the `let-variable` syntax (but it's more verbose)

```
        <ng-template ngFor let-todo=$implicit.to_do let-task [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index" >
  <li>
  <div>
              {{ task.name }}
              {{ todo }}
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let do of todo">
              <input type="text" name="to_do" value="{{ do }}" />
            </div>
            </li>
  </ng-template>
```

Here is a stackblitz showing both ways

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cces4g?file=app%2Fapp.component.html